# Dagger 2 - Inject with default value in constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

How I can inject this constructor:

```
class SomeClass @Inject constructor(
        dep: Dependency,
        context: Context,
        private val otherClass: OtherClass = OtherClass()
)
```

I am only providing Dependency and `Context`... But it says that it cannot provide `OtherClass`. It should need this class, since it has a default value... How can I make this work?

Comment: There are better answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47961375/inject-only-certain-params-in-constructor

Answer (score 2):

Since Dagger is implemented in Java, it cannot use the default value of your constructor when generating code. If you still want to leverage that default value, your only option is to create an `@Provides` annotated function for `SomeClass` in one of your Dagger modules.

```
@Provides
fun provideSomeClass(dep: Dependency, context: Context): SomeClass =
    SomeClass(dep, context)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to inject `OtherClass` as well:

`class OtherClass @Inject constructor()`

you can also play with `@Named` annotation in order to distinct from default implementation and custom `OtherClass`(but I think you should put both injections in module to avoid confusion):

//edit: see following example

```
public static class Pojo {
    final String string;

    Pojo(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return string;
    }
}

@Provides
@Named("custom")
String provideCustomString() {
    return "custom";
}

@Provides
String provideDefaultString() {
    return "default";
}

@Provides
@Named("custom")
Pojo providesCustomPojo(@Named("custom") String custom) {
    return new Pojo(custom);
}

@Provides
Pojo providesDefaultPojo(String defaultString) {
    return new Pojo(defaultString);
}
```

in order to inject custom put `@Inject @Named("custom")` annotations
(sorry for java)

Comment: Hi Lukas, although this solves the problem, I wouldn't like to Inject the OtherClass using Dagger

Comment: Then create a constructor that doesn’t take OtherClass and pass it after via `setOtherClass(otherClass);`