# Inject only certain params in constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I have the presenter

```
class PhonePresenter @Inject constructor(
    private val preference: DataPreference,
    private val ioScheduler: Scheduler = Schedulers.io())
```

`ioScheduler` is a default parameter. I want to inject only `preference: DataPreference`. Now I have the exception

```
[dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] io.reactivex.Scheduler cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

Is there any way to define parameters which I want to inject in a constructor?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Make inject constructor with secondary constructor

```
class PhonePresenter(
    private val preference: DataPreference,
    private val ioScheduler: Scheduler) {        
    @Inject constructor(preference: DataPreference) : this(preference, Schedulers.io())
}
```

Comment: Is this possible in Java as well?

Comment: @octavian In java, just create another constructor which only accept DataPreference as parameter.

Comment: @luffy, Would calling the second constructor with ioSchedular in java, also initialise the DataPreference parameter?

Comment: @Arpit No, DataPreference will only initial automatic by Dagger injection

Comment: How to do it in adapter clas?

Answer (score 5):

Dagger is responsible for injection, let it do its job. Don't use default parameters (Dagger doesn't care), this will force you to make conscious decisions about your dependencies.

Two approaches come to mind:

#### 1. Use Dagger to inject

Create a qualifier so Dagger can differentiate between types of schedulers you might want to inject and a module that provides default IO scheduler.

```
@Qualifier
@MustBeDocumented
annotation class ForIo

@Module
class SchedulerModule {

    @Provides
    @ForIo
    fun provideIoScheduler(): Scheduler = Schedulers.io()
}

class PhonePresenter @Inject constructor(
    private val preference: DataPreference,
    @ForIo private val ioScheduler: Scheduler,
) { ... }
```

Add `SchedulerModule` to your component as usual.

The correct way to supply different arguments is to use a different component with different modules specialized e.g. for testing. Or when testing you'll call the constructor manually.

#### 2. Avoid Dagger in this case

Alternatively you can remove the IO scheduler from constructor parameters. The names suggests it's never going to be anything else than `Schedulers.io()` so it makes little sense to make it parameterized; make it an implementation detail instead.

```
class PhonePresenter @Inject constructor(
    private val preference: DataPreference,
) {

    @VisibleForTesting
    internal var ioScheduler: Scheduler = Schedulers.io()

    ... 
}
```

The above code sample allows you to override `ioScheduler` in tests. Otherwise you can make the property `private`.

Comment: Thanks, I know the first approach but I think it's overhead to get schedulers from modules. The second approach doesn't fit because I want to replace ioScheduler in tests.

Comment: Alright, then the first approach fits your needs. Don't worry about the overhead, as long as `provideIoScheduler` is not scoped or doesn't return `Lazy` or `Provider` Dagger compiler 2.13+ will be able to inline the call - there will be no runtime overhead.

Comment: Default parameters like this are useful when unit testing. For example, when running tests, I want my viewModel to use the test's dispatcher instead of the default.

Comment: @frodo2975 Explicitly set the test dispatcher using constructor in tests, yes. Inject the real dispatcher using dagger, if you're using dagger, because dagger doesn't understand default arguments. No hidden dependencies. What was your point?